# IIS 7 Welcome Page not showing

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7, webserver

**O/S:** Windows 7 ,Home Premium
I have just installed IIS manager Express from Web platform installer and Turned on the IIS7 feature from the Program Feature in control panel.

**Q)** I was playing with IIS Manager (inetmgr) I was able to view the Welcome page on typing `localhost` but after adding some sites and deleting them I'm unable to see any site hosted on IIS and even can't see Welcome page of IIS

**Note:** I was assuming IIS switched off ,but its running
***Services.msc from start menu > run***
[image]

**Progress:**
After trying Update2 from "Andrei Drynov" here is the sanpshot
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is there page iistart.html in C:\inetpub\wwwroot?

[image]

Is the default web site there and running?

[image]

UPDATE:

You can you can uninstall and then install again IIS components like Default document, if you really want that welcome page:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

I was able to reproduce your issue by creating another web site with **site1.com** as a host name in Site Binding and removing the default web site. Remove the host name there and you will be able to open the welcome page again:

[image]

Comment: yes start files exists,its the same welcome page I was referring to

Comment: I deleted the Default WebSite

Comment: In IIS manager, if you go to Content View and right-click on the page and select Browse, what happens?

Comment: I Just tried "Content View and right-click on the page and select Browse" this happened "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to site1.com"

Comment: site1.com?  Check Site Bindings, you probably have that site1.com there. Remove it.

Comment: site1.com removed ,I have again installed the default documents but Default website is not visible

Comment: Stop your Skype - it takes over port 80 sometimes. Completely uninstall IIS using add/remove windows features. Delete inetpub folder. Reboot. Install IIS features again - anew

Comment: I'm not using skype,lets continue over chat ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9796/discussion-between-dotnetsoldier-and-andrei-drynov)

Comment: Special check for Default Web Site status (Running/Stopped) is needed

Answer (score 1):

Is the default IIS website running? that means in the IIS can be on, but the website can still be stopped...try restarting the website...and then try --- right click on website>Manage Website>Browse...

Comment: default IIS website is not running,check the question

Comment: ok...once you install IIS the default website uses the welcome page as the default (iisstart.html)...in order for the welcome page to show up...you need to start the default website...if your question was about the website not starting when you try to start it...then I would recommend you to add more detail to your question...