# IIS not displaying default page or any other page

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, localhost, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 and try to access to the localhost of the IIS Manager, but neither the web site I create or the default web page can be accessed

I tried activating .NET extensibility 3.5 and 4.6 and also activated Static Content to see if that solved the problems, but it appears that it doesn't.

On Microsoft Edge Browser I get this:
"HTTP 404 error 
That’s odd ... Microsoft Edge can’t find this page"

And on Google Chrome I get a blank page.

**EDIT :** I had Skype using the ports 80 and 443, and now on Microsoft Edge I get this "Hmm, we can't reach this page. Try this •Make sure you’ve got the right web address: localhost "
And I also changed the port of IIS to 8080.

Comment: What happens if you simply copy a .jpg into the folder you are creating, and then in IIS Manager go to content view, right click on the .jpg, and choose "Browse"?

Comment: HTTP 404 error
That’s odd... Microsoft Edge can’t find this page
That appears when I select to browse an image

Comment: I had Skype using the ports 80 and 443, and now on Microsoft Edge I get this
"Hmm, we can't reach this page.
Try this
•Make sure you’ve got the right web address: http://localhost "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a page iistart.html in C:intetpub\wwroot? You may want to troubleshoot a few settings. Guide can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048785/iis-7-welcome-page-not-showing) that might be some assistance to you.

Comment: Yes there is a page ... I'll check the guide you provided

Comment: Did you have any luck with that guide?

Comment: Yes, in one of the answers someone said to activate almost all the fields in Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web -> Application Development Features
By doing that I now can access the localhost.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, just went "uninstall" ISS and restart the PC, then go back and install it again, now it's working.